# How do I log new bans?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm working on something and I need to add ban logging, I tried something but it doesn't send anything.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
client.on('guildBanAdd', async (guild, user) => {
 let Banch = await client.channels.cache.get('ID')
  const fetchedLogs = await guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: 'MEMBER_BAN_ADD',
    });
    const banLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();

    if (!banLog) return console.log(`${user.tag} was banned from ${guild.name} but no audit log could be found.`);

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`Member Banned`)
.setDescription(`${guild.name}`)
.setColor("RED")
.addField(`Member`, `\n${username}`)
   Banch.send(embed)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('guildBanAdd', async (guild, user) => {
    const banned = await guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        type: 'MEMBER_BAN_ADD',
        limit: 1
    });

    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('ID');
    if(!channel) return console.log(`Channel was not found!`);

    const userbanned = banned.entries.first();

    const { executor, target } = userbanned; // get the user who banned the user and the user that got banned

    if(target.id !== user.id) return console.log(`Invalid data in the audit logs!`); // check if the user that got banned in the Audit Logs is the user that is banned

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Member Banned`)
    .setDescription(`${guild.name}`)
    .setColor("RED")
    .addField(`Member`, `${target.username}`);
    channel.send(embed).catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
    });
});
```